# Magento2 : sales_payment_transaction table not updating

Tags: magento-2.1, sales-order

I'm creating a custom payment module in magento2 and create success controller, I want to update order status and transaction. My code as below :

```
// create invoice : this is working
$invoiceService = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Service\InvoiceService');
$invoice = $invoiceService->prepareInvoice($order);
$invoice->register();
$invoice->save();

// update order status : this is working
$order->setState(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PROCESSING, true);
$order->setStatus(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PROCESSING);
$order->addStatusToHistory($order->getStatus(), 'Tseting : Order processed successfully with reference '. $tracking_id);
$order->save();

// make transaction : this is not working           
$payment = $order->getPayment();
$payment->setLastTransId($tracking_id);
$payment->setTransactionId($tracking_id);
$formatedPrice = $order->getBaseCurrency()->formatTxt(
    $order->getGrandTotal()
);

$trans = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Transaction\Builder');

$message = __('The authorized amount is %1.', $formatedPrice);
$transaction = $trans->setPayment($payment)
->setOrder($order)
->setTransactionId($tracking_id)
->setFailSafe(true)
->build(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Transaction::TYPE_CAPTURE);

$payment->addTransactionCommentsToOrder(
    $transaction,
    $message
);
$payment->setParentTransactionId(null);
$payment->save();
```

`sales_payment_transaction` table not updating from above code.

How to complete my transaction after payment success?